# How to reproduce average marginal effects from xtlogit model

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, random-effects, marginal-effects

I am interested in reproducing average marginal effects from a random effects logit model (run in Stata using `xtlogit`). I understand how to reproduce the average marginal effects from a `logit` model using the Delta method. For instance, in the code below, I successfully reproduce the average marginal effect for `age` reported in `margins`.

```
*** Stata code
* download data
webuse union, clear

* calculate delta and copy variable of interest - age
sum age
gen xdelta = r(sd)/1000
clonevar age_ = age

* run logit model and calculate average marginal effect using margins
logit union age_
margins,dydx(age_)

* calculate average marginal effect by hand - mean of xme equals result from margins above
predict p1
replace age_ = age_+xdelta
predict p2
gen xme = (p2 - p1) / xdelta
sum xme

* calculate average marginal effect at fixed value of age using margins
margins,at(age=(16))

* calculate average marginal effect by hand - mean of p3 equals result from margins above
replace age_ = 16
predict p3
sum p3
```

Where I'm struggling is reproducing the average marginal effects for a `xtlogit` model.

```
*** Stata code
* download data and designate panel variables
webuse union, clear
xtset idcode year

* run xtlogit model
xtlogit union age

* calculate average marginal effects - can't figure out how to reproduce these estimates :(
margins, dydx(*)
margins, at(age=(16))
```

Any help for figuring out how to reproduce the `xtlogit` marginal effects is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

----- edited to make clearer that I'm interested in reproducing estimates reported by `margins`

Comment: When you ask about how to calculate "by hand" it's not clear. There isn't much done "by hand" in your successful example. If you're interested in how margins works after `xtlogit, re` [Cameron & Trivedi  2010](https://www.stata.com/bookstore/microeconometrics-stata/) page 630 has good starting point and recommends an estimation approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I guess "by hand" was not the correct phrase - I meant that I would like to reproduce or replicate the marginal effects reported by ```margins```. I have modified my question. Also, I will check out the reference you passed along!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but essentially the problem boils down to the fact

$$\Pr(y_{it}=1 \vert x_{it})=\int\Lambda(u_i + x_{it}'\beta)\cdot \varphi(0,\sigma_u^2) du_i$$

where $\varphi()$ is the normal density. In your code, you are effectively setting the random effect $u_i$ to zero (which is what `predict(pu0)` does). This sets the RE to its average, which may not be what you had it mind. Of course, $u_i$ is not observed or even estimated by `xtlogit, re`, so if you want to replicate what `predict(pr)` does, you need to integrate the random effect out to get the unconditional probability using the estimated variance.

One way to do this in Stata is to use the user-written `integrate` command to do one dimensional numerical integration like this:

```
webuse union, clear
xtset idcode year
xtlogit union age, nolog
margins, at(age=(16)) predict(pr)
margins, dydx(*) at(age=16) predict(pr)
capture ssc install integrate
/* phat at age 16 */
integrate, f(invlogit(x - 3.0079682 + .01929225*16)*normalden(x,0,2.477537654945496)) l(-10) u(10) vectorise quadpts(1000)
/* ME at age 16 */
integrate, f(invlogit(x - 3.0079682 + .01929225*16)*(1-invlogit(x - 3.0079682 + .01929225*16))*(.01929225)*normalden(x,0,2.477537654945496)) l(-10) u(10) vectorise quadpts(1000)
```

You can probably get even better precision if you use the actual coefficients (like _b[_cons] and e(sigma_u)) instead of pasting the values in.

There might be a more efficient way to do this using Mata, Python, or even with a simulation approach, but I will leave that up to you to work out. You can also get posterior modal estimates of the REs using `xtmelogit`.

Comment: I always forget that SO does not support LaTeX. Please let me know if any of that is unclear.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thank you!